# Flow of hot gasses around the pipe

Tags: thermal-conduction, thermal-insulation, ansys-workbench, thermal-radiation

I have the following problem: there is a copper pipe getting through a wooden wall. On one side of the wall (hot side), I have elevated temperature which is defined by radiation and convection. On the cold side I have ambient temperature, again defined by radiation and convection (picture in the attachment). It should resemble the experiment done in oven.

However, between the wooden wall and the copper pipe there is a little gap which (in reality) lets some of the hot gasses to pass from one side to another. So far, the temperatures on the cold side are much lower comparing to the experiment.

Is there any way to simulate this stream of hot gasses getting though the gap around the pipe and how to do it? Or if I am doing something completely wrong with defining the parameters? Is this even possible to do with Workbench only?[image]

Comment: If you seal the gap, do the values then agree?

Comment: Well, experiments are already done, and during the experiment the gap was not completely sealed (as it happens quite often in reality).

Comment: Bad seals like that tend to be the cause of fires....

Comment: Have you considered just adding an additional thermal convection path in parallel with the wall? The simple case is to put an unknown resistance and adjust it empirically until your model fits the data.

Comment: You can perform such simulation if you have the CFD module in ANSYS (Fluent). You would be able to compute the heat flux form the steam into the pipe at the gap and on the cold side.